# Broken pipe, closing control connection. while piping small file through funzip using wget

Tags: ftp, pipe, wget

I'm trying to download a small zip file (1159 bytes) and pipe it through funzip. This works great with larger files fro that server. However three small files give me an error:
Broken pipe, closing control connection.

I use the following code:

```
wget -O - --ftp-user=username --ftp-password=secret ftp://server/small-file.zip | funzip
```

Also downloading the file directly works good, only the piping to funzip doesn't work. I suspect the file is too small.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Edit: Size doesn't seem to matter (don't let the girls tell you otherwise :)), even files of 400 bytes are not giving errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if nobody can answer it, I'll answer it myself

I found there are two solutions, one is limiting the download rate for wget

```
--limit-rate=1000
```

This works for the files of around 1kb but now sometimes larger files seem to suffer from the same error. It also slows down the whole process.

Now I just pipe the download through a script that sleeps 1 second at the end. This seems to solve it.